# Detect AC(on/off) and Window(open/close) of CAR using OBD

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, obd-ii

Is there any way to detect AC(air conditioner) and Window(open/close) using OBD.

I am refering below links for OBD reader but I can't able to find any way to detect AC(air conditioner) and Window(open/close).

https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api

https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader

Comment: OBD II is designed primarily for engine monitoring, not for accessories like power windows and climate control. Anything you can do with OBD II related to these systems (assuming you can do anything at all) is going to be specific to the manufacturer of the car, possibly even specific to the particular model.  I don't have hard evidence for this, but I would suspect that most cars' computers have no way of knowing whether a window is open.

Answer (score 0):

OBDII is designed for monitoring whether it is of the engines or other electronic controls. This totally depends on the protocol your vehicle is using.

If your vehicle protocol supports the electronic control monitoring of the car then you can try this command "AT MA" where AT = Attention and MA = Monitor All.

you may find further guide in ELM datasheet. ELM is the chip used by OBD scanner to communicate car ECU.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can, but there is not any standard to do this. Each manufacturer can have more than one can-bus. You should work for all car models separately. And you may not be do this by using clone elm327. Because clone elm327's can-h and can-l pins connected to pin 6 and pin 14. And probably windows and ac don't communicate on this bus.

OBD2 pinout diagram:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJB6W.png

For example my 2010 opel/vauxhall astra's AC data flows on MS-CAN which is connected to pin 3 and pin 11. And the doors communicates on SW-CAN which is connected to pin 1 and pin 5.

This is the remote door control POC: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPOk6LBckMg

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. OBD is really just and "emissions" protocol. The data that it carries will have, at best, bi-directional controls for emission related systems and engine management, and that's really being hopeful. Comfort systems, such as power windows, power seats, audio, instrumentation are usually on a proprietary protocol, some are well documented, Chrysler's LIN network is documented fairly well within automotive diagnostic manuals. Some manufactures , GM, use the CAN protocol, again fairly well documented within automotive technician diagnostic information.